# Is meaningful to use word2vec represent a hash value?

Tags: neural-network, word2vec

I have an execution path containing a nondeterministic length of sequence of packets. For example, /A/B/C/D/E, /A/E/G/B, etc, where the capital characters are packets represented by hash value. Is it meaningful if I represent each packets using word2vec?

Comment: I suppose how meaningful it is depends on your purpose. Also, do you have vector representations already? If not, from where will you generate them?

Comment: @kubuntu I use the hash values to identify packets. Packets compose execution paths, which record whether the system's global state goes wrong or not. Within a path, packets do not appear repeatedly. But the path's' length and order of packets varies from each other. My ultimate purpose is, given a fragment of new path, starts from  the beginning but not necessarily ends at the termination point, predict whether this path leads to a wrong system global state.

Answer (score 0):

Word2Vec relies on predictive co-occurrences to achieve its usefully-dense embedded representations.

If you're using a strong hash that turns a single bit's difference in the packets into a totally different token, that would likely be unhelpful 'noise' to Word2Vec.

If it's a somewhat-semantic hash, that serves to give similar-packets similar tokens, it may be appropriate and helpful to the Word2Vec algorithm.

When you mention your end-goal is to "predict whether this path leads to a wrong system global state", I wonder if Word2Vec word-vectors will be an appropriate tool. Word2Vec doesn't have much depth/recurrence/series-statefulness in its model; it is unlikely to capture much knowledge about an underlying "state machine" or "illegal states", although it might help position a 'packet' to be similar to others based on similar predecessor/successor packets (as a helpful feed into some other more stateful analysis).